# How count how many one bit have in byte, in Golang?

Tags: go

Suppose I have two variables, that only use 6 bits:

```
var a byte = 31  // 00011111
var b byte = 50  // 00110010
```

The first (`a`) have more one bits than the `b`, however the `b` is greater than `a` of course, *so is not possible use `a > b`.*

To achieve what I need, I do one loop:

```
func countOneBits(byt byte) int {
    var counter int
    var divider byte

    for divider = 32; divider >= 1; divider >>= 1 {
        if byt & divider == divider {
            counter++
        }

    }

    return counter
}
```

[This works,](https://play.golang.org/p/yri7YSpnYx) I can use `countOneBits(a) > countOneBits(b)`...

---

But I don't think is the best solution for this case, I don't think this need a loop and because of it I'm here.

**Have a better alternative (in performance aspect) to count how many `1` have in six bits?**

Comment: Go 1.9 (to be released in August 2017 - pre release is no available) will ship https://beta.golang.org/pkg/math/bits/#OnesCount and other bit manipulation functions. As we can read from [documentation](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.9#math-bits)  It will be optimized per architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the input is a single byte probably a lookup table is the best option... only takes 256 bytes and you get code like

```
var count = bitcount[input];
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that this function will be available in the package[`math/bits`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.9/src/math/bits/bits.go) in the next Go release (1.9 this August) here is the code for a 32-bit integer.

```
// OnesCount32 returns the number of one bits ("population count") in x.
func OnesCount32(x uint32) int {
    return int(pop8tab[x>>24] + pop8tab[x>>16&0xff] + pop8tab[x>>8&0xff] + pop8tab[x&0xff])
}
```

Where the `pop8tab` is defined [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/83bc4a2feed1c7dc37026278364772483fe73618/src/math/bits/bits_tables.go#L28). And for your question in particular : 8bits

```
func OnesCount8(x uint8) int {
    return int(pop8tab[x])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to count bits with binary operations. See this [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel).

```
func bitSetCount(v byte) byte {
    v = (v & 0x55) + ((v>>1) & 0x55)
    v = (v & 0x33) + ((v>>2) & 0x33)
    return (v + (v>>4)) & 0xF
}
```

You'll have to benchmark to see if this is faster than the lookup table which is the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 1):

there is POPCNT golang version:

https://github.com/tmthrgd/go-popcount